# Let $p ≥ 3$ be a prime number. Show that: $\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} k^{p-1} ≡ −1 \: mod \:p $

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

Let p ≥ 3 be a prime number. Show that:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} k^{p-1} ≡ −1 \: mod \:p. $$

We have no idea how to solve this problem. Would be great if anyone could help us! :)

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Does Fermat ring a bell?

Comment: you might want to look at [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2722409/proof-that-sum-limits-i-fracp-1i-is-divisible-by-p)

Comment: We know that it relates to Fermats theorem, but we have no clue how to solve the equasion itself (if thats whats it called, sorry my english might be off)

Comment: Don't worry about the sum,  what is $k^{p-1}$ for $0\le k \le p-1$ according to Fermat? .... Hint try it will $p =7$, if you actually *try* to figure $0^6 + 1^6 + 2^6 + 3^6 +4^6 + 5^6 +6^6$ the solution should be *obvious*..... but seriously,  What does Fermat say $k^6\pmod 7$ should be?

Comment: Can you write out what the exact wording of Fermat's Little theorem says?  Actually read what it says.....  (More hints.   What is $\sum_{k=1}^m 1$?  Hint 2:  If $-1\equiv x \pmod p$ and $0 \le x < p$ then what is $x$?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every $k<p$ from Fermat we get $k^p-k=k(k^{p-1}-1)=0\mod p$ and because $k<p$ and $p$ is prime, we can divide this by $k$ and get $k^{p-1}-1=0\mod p$. Sum this up for $k\in\{1,...,p-1\}$ and we get $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} k^{p-1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{p-1} 1=p-1=-1\mod p$.